# Samsung GT-i9000 (Galaxy S), Android 2.3.6, MTP and Linux

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, linux, usb-connection-mode

Is it possible to connect this device to Linux workstation over USB using MTP mode? I've tried a few times using different tools but no success. GMTP just don't work, mtp-tools don't work reliably, etc.

Comment: Why would you want to use MTP as opposed to simply mounting the SD card as a device?

Comment: Because connection device as Mass Storage works painfully slow on linux, transfers speed about ~200-500 kbps, it's almost unusable.

Comment: Well, MTP also doesn't require “Safe umount”, sync etc.

Comment: Strange, I get much higher speeds than that myself. Also, why *wouldn't* you want safe unmount, etc? Seems like that way lies file corruption?

Answer (score 4):

Finally  found an answer: it's not possible. Samsung implementation of MTP works incorrectly so device cannot be used in standard tools like GMTP.

Moreover, MTP application on the phone crashes sometimes during data transfer.